# Firebase Real Database data fetching

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nsdictionary

I am trying the get the following values as variables

[image]

But my code gives me nil

```
ref.child("users").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    // Get user value
    let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
    let userInfo = value?["UserInfo"] as? NSDictionary
    let data = userInfo?["lat"] as? String ?? ""
    print(data)


    // ...
}) { (error) in
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

ًWhat am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just to do a small change here:

```
let data = userInfo?["lat"] as? String ?? ""
```

Latitude is not a String, but an Int, so cast as Int:

```
let data = userInfo?["lat"] as? Int ?? 0
```